# External stylesheets can't resolve path in angular app

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I'm trying to integrate to my angular app a website created by a friend. He sent me those files :

- css/
- fonts/
- js/
- index.html

So I added index.html's imports (css and js) to my angular.json and body's content to my component's template.

However, when running  `ng serve`, I get a lot of errors, coming from stylesheets included previously. For instance, here's one

```
ERROR in ./src/assets/home-assets/css/jquery-ui.css (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./src/assets/home-assets/css/jquery-ui.css)
Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError: C:\Users\bonna\Work\Natan\natan-website\front-end\src\assets\home-assets\css\jquery-ui.css:430:25: Can't resolve 'images/ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240.png' in 'C:\Users\bonna\Work\Natan\natan-website\front-end\src\assets\home-assets\css'

  428 | .ui-state-error .ui-icon,
  429 | .ui-state-error-text .ui-icon {
> 430 |         background-image: url("images/ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240.png");
      |                                ^
  431 | }
  432 |
```

Every error seem to have the same origin : images' paths

Does any one have a solution ?

Comment: Is your images in assets?

Comment: Those images are requested by the lib (here jquery-ui), but no I do not have included them myself. However, everything surprisingly works when I just open the index.html, while these images are not in the files I received